# Ssh keys on docker gitlab-ce

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, gitlab

The announcement for [GitLab 13.10](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/03/22/gitlab-13-10-released/) has a [deprecation notice](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/03/22/gitlab-13-10-released/#remove-authorized_keys-integration-for-ssh-key-lookup) for using authorized_keys for ssh keys:

> *The first mechanism (integration via authorized keys ) is vulnerable to both race conditions and out-of-order execution issues, making it hard to scale. Because of this it will be removed in GitLab 14.0. Refer to [issue #212227](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/212227) for details.*

Docs for fast ssh key lookup ([Fast lookup of authorized SSH keys in the database | GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/operations/fast_ssh_key_lookup)) say that

> *For Omnibus Docker, AuthorizedKeysCommand is setup by default in GitLab 11.11 and later.*

When I poke into my gitlab container at its ssh config files, I do not see `AuthorizedKeysCommand`. However, I also cannot find any reference in `/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys` of my actual SSH keys, suggesting that it is in fact using fast lookup instead of the system `authorized_keys` file.

My configuration in *Admin Area > Network > Performance optimization* has enabled `Write to "authorized_keys" file`. My understanding of that is that it is a backup for deployment keys, not that that file will be used for all authentication.

Since the `authorized_keys` file will reach deprecation in GitLab-14 (two months away?), I’m looking ahead. How do I know if removal of support for that file will break me? I can always uncheck the "write to authorized_keys", but I don't expect that that would have immediate effects.

Comment: I'm confident enough that there will be  instructions provided in this (future, yet to be created) page: https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/update/gitlab_14_changes.html

Comment: It doesn't seem the "norm" for gitlab to wait until the last second to wipe functionality away without clear indication of how to configure it. I don't know that you're wrong, per se, and I too hope that they'd include some better verbiage for this (breaking?) change. Thanks.

Comment: `AuthorizedKeysCommand` is used within sshd_config, and, if not present, then it's not configured. Check `man sshd_config` to see if within the doc, otherwise you may be using an older sshd in which case you'll need to upgrade to use it.

Comment: Sure, but that's not what I'm asking. I believe that the gitlab processes should be managing their sshd configuration, so I shouldn't need to into the container every time and change its configuration ... or build my own derivative image that changes that file (that will likely be overridden by the process anyway).

Comment: Was it `/assets/sshd_config` that you checked?

Comment: @A.B, for your first comment, the `gitlab_14_changes.html` unfortunately contains neither `ssh` nor `authorized`; while I think it is a great comment, unfortunately it has not yet come to fruition. For your second comment, I grepped just about every file under `/etc/`, `/var/opt/gitlab`, and a few other places (I don't recall exactly), via something like `find /etc /var/opt -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -il authorized`.

Comment: In your link: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/operations/fast_ssh_key_lookup , it's written that for Omnibus Docker, the sshd_config file is in /assets/sshd_config , that's why I was asking this in my 2nd comment.

Comment: Good point. I'm almost there. Yes, in `/assets/sshd_config` I see `AuthorizedKeysCommand` (points to a gitlab compiled executable). It does mention the location of two `authorized_file` instances, and I found the `authorized_file` that contains me key ... and I had looked there before but was looking for the wrong keywords. Now that I found where a current ssh key is stored, I need to look at implementing the change for the deprecation. Thanks!

Comment: Just follow the test described "Confirm that SSH is working by commenting out your user’s key in the authorized_keys file..." . From this doc and what you just wrote I understand it's already in place.

Comment: @A.B, thanks for the patient discussion on this. I finally found "my key", commented it out, and am comfortable now with the soon-to-be disabled `authorized_keys` file. If you'd like to write up an answer, I'll happily accept/upvote it and give you the credit you deserve. Thanks again!

Comment: Made an answer out of these comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's [linked documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/operations/fast_ssh_key_lookup) ([giving here the *ce*](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/operations/fast_ssh_key_lookup) version which is identical) [tells](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/operations/fast_ssh_key_lookup#setting-up-fast-lookup-via-gitlab-shell):

> Add the following to your sshd_config file. This is usually located at
> `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, but **it will be `/assets/sshd_config` if you’re
> using Omnibus Docker**:
>
> ```
> Match User git    # Apply the AuthorizedKeysCommands to the git user only
>   AuthorizedKeysCommand /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell-authorized-keys-check git %u %k
>   AuthorizedKeysCommandUser git
> Match all    # End match, settings apply to all users again
> ```

Because the configuration file is in an uncommon place, it might not have been found.

The documentation then tells, as OP already wrote:

> ⓘ For Omnibus Docker, `AuthorizedKeysCommand` is setup by default in GitLab 11.11 and later.

So Omnibus Docker is already configured to use GitLab's dedicated command in complement to the `authorized_keys` file. There's nothing to prepare for version 14 in the *Omnibus Docker* version, it's already ready for the change (that's most likely not the case for the *standard* Omnibus version) where there shouldn't be an `authorized_keys` file anymore and the command `gitlab-shell-authorized-keys-check` will completely take over.

To double-check it's already using the new authentication method, one can follow the test suggested in the documentation:

> Confirm that SSH is working by commenting out your user’s key in the
> `authorized_keys` file (start the line with a `#` to comment it), and
> attempting to pull a repository.
>
> A successful pull would mean that GitLab was able to find the key in
> the database, since it is not present in the file anymore.